# Query string after .html in htaccess doesn't work.why?

Tags: .htaccess

My site is written in PHP. I have changed its urls from php to html and reconvert it in `.htaccess` file.

I put autocomplete jquery ui widget in a page of my site and its call to remote file to get suggested items doesn't work. Because the remote url is changed to

```
search.html?term=spr
```

I put this line in htaccess file but it doesn't matche because it doesn't consider anything after `\.html`.

```
RewriteRule ^search\.html?term=([^-]+)$ search.php?term=$1 [L,NC,NS]
```

I also tried

```
RewriteRule ^search\.html\?term=([^-]+)$ search.php?term=$1 [L,NC,NS]
```

but both doesn't work.

Would you help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell Apache to append the query string (QSA = **Q**uery **s**tring **a**ppend)

```
 RewriteRule ^search\.html$ search.php [L,NC,NS,QSA]
```

`^search\.html$` is a regular expression matching a literal `search.html`. `^` matches from the beginning, `$` matches till the end and `\.` matches a literal dot instead of any character (the special meaning of a dot in regular expressions)

This rule...

- Matches a request for `search.html` (`RewriteRule ^search\.html$`)
- and rewrites it to `search.php`,
- processing no rules after this one ([`[L]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)),
- match case insensitive (e.g. `Search.HTML` would be rewritten too) ([`[NC]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc))
- will not be used for subrequests ([`[NS]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ns))
- and will finally append the original Query string after `search.php` ([`[QSA]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa))

For an overview of flags:

- [Apache docs on RewriteRule flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags):